# Dataweave transformation for input variable to soap header

Tags: mule, transform, soapheader, dataweave

I need the value in input variable to be added to soap header, using Dataweave - I was using datamapper earlier, but since it's no more supported, want to do through Dataweave.

I'm not able to map between the data variable and outbound property in Anypoint studio. I even tried with multiple variables but no use.

Does anyone has an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to set an outbound property from a flow variable using the 'Output' drop down in DW, choose 'Outbound Property'. This feature is described [here](https://developer.mulesoft.com/docs/display/EARLYACCESS/Using+DataWeave+in+Studio), see section 'Handling Multiple Outputs'.

Comment: Thank you. For some reason when I was ussing scaffold feature, it was not working earlier, but now it works. I also wasn't prepending 'flowVars.' which was resulting in syntax error.